# Accessing .htaccess in Zend Framework while running files from command prompt

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

In my current application, I have to run some files from command prompt. When I set the Environment to Production in .htaccess file, the application is able to read the configuration related to production when it is run through web browser. But while running from command prompt I am getting the configuration of development. How to get the production configuration while running through command prompt?

Please help me. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can specify environment before executing your script:

```
APPLICATION_ENV=testing php script.php
```

and then access it in your script.php `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']`

Personally I'm doing this by extending Zend_Tool_Project_Provider_Abstract and passing environment as argument, see this example: https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/zf-doctrine-base-tables-generator/blob/master/library/My/Component/DoctrineProvider.php

Comment: Thanks. But for our application we cannot pass environment as parameter. When i run the file from command prompt, it should be populated from bootstrap.php.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a separate php script for running via CLI, you could set the environment variable there:

Something like this in `cli.php`:

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    putenv("APPLICATION_ENV=production");
}
```

Alternatively, you could inspect `$argv` and get the environment from there. Maybe something like this:

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    foreach ($argv as $val) {
        if (strpos($val, '=')) {
            $bits = explode('=', $val) {
                if ($bits[0] == 'environment') {
                    putenv("APPLICATION_ENV=" . $bits[1]);                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would then run your app as :

```
php index.php environment=production
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All. I too got one solution. 
1. create a new ini file (say environment.ini) that holds APPLICATION_ENV = 'production'.
2. Modify the zf_config.php to get the required environment configuration. It worked for both command prompt and browser.

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file(APPLICATION_PATH."/configs/environment.ini");
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
        || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') :(($ini_array['APPLICATION_ENV']?$ini_array['APPLICATION_ENV']:'development'))));
```